# Hibernate Java - cannot deserialize/invalid stream header error

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I am creating a Java Spring Boot project. I had a foreign key issue with one of the tables where null value was inserted into the foreign key field. I couldn't resolve the issue so I recreated the entity code using Hibernate configuration of Eclipse IDE. Now I am able to start the application but I am getting the below errors in Postman.

```
{
    "timestamp": 1519124137813,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException",
    "message": "could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize",
    "path": "/employee/"
}

{
    "timestamp": 1519125015097,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException",
    "message": "could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize",
    "path": "/employee/101/timelog/tabdata"
}
```

My doubt: I am using a localdateconverter.I doubt whether it is a date conversion issue

//employee

```
// default package
// Generated Feb 18, 2018 3:41:47 PM by Hibernate Tools 5.2.3.Final

/**
 * Employee generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee", catalog = "timesheet")
public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8265127921786950582L;
    private Integer empId;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Organisation organisation;
    private String designation;
    private String email;
    private String empName;
    private String gender;
    private LocalDate joinDate;
    private Set<Timelog> timelogs = new HashSet<Timelog>(0);

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(Organisation organisation) {
        this.organisation = organisation;
    }

    public Employee(Organisation organisation, String designation, String email, String empName, String gender,
            LocalDate joinDate, Set<Timelog> timelogs) {
        this.organisation = organisation;
        this.designation = designation;
        this.email = email;
        this.empName = empName;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.joinDate = joinDate;
        this.timelogs = timelogs;
    }


    public Employee(String empName, LocalDate joinDate, String gender, String designation, String email) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.empName = empName;
        this.joinDate = joinDate;
        this.gender = gender;

        this.designation = designation;
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "emp_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getEmpId() {
        return this.empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(Integer empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "org_id", nullable = false)
    public Organisation getOrganisation() {
        return this.organisation;
    }

    public void setOrganisation(Organisation organisation) {
        this.organisation = organisation;
    }

    @Column(name = "designation", length = 45)
    public String getDesignation() {
        return this.designation;
    }

    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
    }

    @Column(name = "email", length = 45)
    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Column(name = "emp_name", length = 45)
    public String getEmpName() {
        return this.empName;
    }

    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }

    @Column(name = "gender", length = 10)
    public String getGender() {
        return this.gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    //@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "join_date", length = 10)
    public LocalDate getJoinDate() {
        return this.joinDate;
    }

    public void setJoinDate(LocalDate joinDate) {
        this.joinDate = joinDate;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "employee")
    public Set<Timelog> getTimelogs() {
        return this.timelogs;
    }

    public void setTimelogs(Set<Timelog> timelogs) {
        this.timelogs = timelogs;
    }

    public void addLog(Timelog log) {
        Set<Timelog> set = this.getTimelogs();
        set.add(log);
        this.setTimelogs(set);
    }

}
```

//organisation

```
/**
 * Organisation generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "organisation", catalog = "timesheet")
public class Organisation implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5790958954280933376L;
    private Integer orgId;
    private String address;
    private Integer contactNo;
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<Employee>(0);

    public Organisation() {
    }

    public Organisation(String address, Integer contactNo, String email, String name, Set<Employee> employees) {
        this.address = address;
        this.contactNo = contactNo;
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
        this.employees = employees;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "org_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getOrgId() {
        return this.orgId;
    }

    public void setOrgId(Integer orgId) {
        this.orgId = orgId;
    }

    @Column(name = "address", length = 45)
    public String getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Column(name = "contact_no")
    public Integer getContactNo() {
        return this.contactNo;
    }

    public void setContactNo(Integer contactNo) {
        this.contactNo = contactNo;
    }

    @Column(name = "email", length = 45)
    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", length = 45)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "organisation")
    public Set<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return this.employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(Set<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }

}
```

//Timelog table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "timelog", catalog = "timesheet")
public class Timelog implements java.io.Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1871977717947082854L;
private Integer id;
private Employee employee;
private LocalDate logDate;
private String project;
private Float timetaken;

public Timelog() {
}

public Timelog(Employee employee) {
    this.employee = employee;
}

public Timelog(Employee employee, LocalDate logDate, String project, Float timetaken) {
    this.employee = employee;
    this.logDate = logDate;
    this.project = project;
    this.timetaken = timetaken;
}

public Timelog(LocalDate logDate, String project, float timetaken) {
    this.logDate = logDate;
    this.project = project;
    this.timetaken = timetaken;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "emp_id", nullable = false)
public Employee getEmployee() {
    return this.employee;
}

public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
    this.employee = employee;
}

//@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "logDate", length = 10)
public LocalDate getLogdate() {
    return this.logDate;
}

public void setLogdate(LocalDate logDate) {
    this.logDate = logDate;
}

@Column(name = "project", length = 45)
public String getProject() {
    return this.project;
}

public void setProject(String project) {
    this.project = project;
}

@Column(name = "timetaken", precision = 12, scale = 0)
public Float getTimetaken() {
    return this.timetaken;
}

public void setTimetaken(Float timetaken) {
    this.timetaken = timetaken;
}

}
```

I have included the codes of the entities I am using - organisation,employee and timelog.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved the issue.
It was caused due to renaming of my folder in which the  entity code is recreated.I changed the folder name to what it was previously and issue got resolved